# Android Listview SimpleCursorAdapter Error

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, cursor, simplecursoradapter

"QuoteTable" is a java class file that defines a database. The code below works perfectly fine.

```
// mCategory = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.category); - created during OnCreate method 

private void fillData() {

// Fields from the database (projection)
// Must include the _id column for the adapter to work
String category = (String) mCategory.getSelectedItem();
String[] from = new String[] { QuoteTable.COLUMN_QUOTE };
// Fields on the UI to which we map
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.label };

getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.motivate_row, null, from,
    to, 0);

setListAdapter(adapter); }
```

What I want to do is, select particular quotes from "QuoteTable" depending on the category selected in the Spinner. This category should match the COLUMN_CATEGORY field in "QuoteTable." So I tried this -

```
 private void fillData() {
String[] from = null;
// Fields from the database (projection)
// Must include the _id column for the adapter to work
if(category.equals("All")){
       from = new String[] { QuoteTable.COLUMN_QUOTE };
}
else{
        if(category.equals(QuoteTable.COLUMN_CATEGORY))
              from = new String[] { QuoteTable.COLUMN_QUOTE };
}
// Fields on the UI to which we map
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.label };

getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.motivate_row, null, from,
    to, 0);

setListAdapter(adapter);  }
```

/* this error is resolved */ This gives me a "SimpleCursorAdapter" error at `if(category == "All")` Why is this the case? I've already used Cursor in another class to run a query in saving the database. This is merely my "View" and I want don't want to re-use that code.

Okay, now the previous (above mentioned) error is resolved. I had to fix the spinner in the layout file. However, although now there are no errors (runtime or compile time), the code logically does not do what I intend it to do. The spinner is present, but on selecting different options, nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

String comparison should be done using `.equals()` method: `"All".equals(category)`

Comment: alright I've corrected that. now I get a Null Pointer Exception

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.equals()` to compare strings

```
if(category.equals("All")){
```

Check

[What is the difference between == vs equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion)

You have

```
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.motivate_row, null, from,
to, 0);
```

The third param is null should be a cursor

Comment: alright I've corrected that. now I get a Null Pointer Exception

Comment: @user2201545 post the stacktrace

Comment: @user2201545 third param to the constructor of cursor adapter is null

Comment: @user2201545 post the stacktrace by extracting the exception part or forget further help. links won't help

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{b.example.m/b.example.m.mOverviewActivity}:java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: So I have to create a cursor object again? In the previous section also i passed null as third param, that time no error?